# undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'

Tags: c++, gcc, undefined-reference

Getting this error while compiling C++ code:

```
undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
```

Options already tried:

1. added -fno-stack-protector while compiling - did not work, error persists
2. added a dummy implementation of void __stack_chk_fail(void) in my code. Still getting the same error.

Detailed Error:

```
/u/ac/alanger/gurobi/gurobi400/linux64/lib/libgurobi_c++.a(Env.o)(.text+0x1034): In function `GRBEnv::getPar/u/ac/alanger/gurobi/gurobi400/linux64/lib/libgurobi_c++.a(Env.o)(.text+0x1034): In function `GRBEnv::getParamInfo(GRB_StringParam, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)':
: undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
amInfo(GRB_StringParam, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)':
: **undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'**
```

Earlier, I was getting 10's of such errors. Found out that there was a version mismatch between the `gcc` of the pre-compiled libraries I am using and the `gcc` version I was using to compile the code. Updated `gcc` and now I am getting only 2 of these errors.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

libgurobi_c++.a was compiled with `-fno-stack-protector` (obviously).

A few things come to mind:

1. add `-fstack-protector` when linking.  This will make sure that libssp gets linked.
2. Manually link `-lssp`
3. Make your dummy version of `__stack_chk_fail(void)` in it's own object file and and add this .o file to your linker command **AFTER** libgurobi_c++.a.  GCC/G++ resolves symbols from left to right during linking so despite your code having the function defined, a copy of an object containing the __stack_chk_fail symbol needs to be on the linker line to the right of libgurobi_c++.a.

Comment: 1. I had added -fno-stack-protector earlier but that had not helped. 
2. Thanks a lot, adding -lssp worked. 
3. Thanks, a  lot! This information was useful. I had forgotten this.

Comment: Glad that solved it.  Had you added -fno-stack-protector during linking?  Maybe it put the -lssp in the wrong order, who knows...

Comment: Though it compiled when I run the program I get this error:

./jetAlloc: error while loading shared libraries: libssp.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Why would adding "no" `-fno-stack-protector` make sure libssp gets linked? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Indeed, it should be `-fstack-protector`, unless you're wanting to disable it in the linked static library and rebuild that instead.

Comment: Another clean solution sometimes is to check if `_FORTIFY_SOURCE` is defined anywhere in the source or build files and if it does remove that (or set it to `0`).

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same issue: c++ code with an implementation of void `__stack_chk_fail(void)` showing several `undefined reference to __stack_chk_fail` errors when compiling.

My solution was to define `__stack_chk_fail(void)` as `extern "C"`:

```
extern "C" {
__stack_chk_fail(void)
{
...
}
}
```

This suppressed the compilation error :)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Makes sense. Reason is the C++ name mangling (can be seen in the output of nm) which makes it impossible for the linker to find the symbol __stack_chk_fail.

Answer (score 1):

In gentoo I had the same problem and i resolved creating 2 files. The first contain the option to be parsed by emerge and passed to gcc:

```
/etc/portage/env/nostackprotector.conf
CFLAGS="-fno-stack-protector -O2"
```

And the second tells which package should use this settings:

```
/etc/portage/package.env/nostackprotector
x11-libs/vte nostackprotector.conf
sys-libs/glibc nostackprotector.conf
www-client/chromium nostackprotector.conf
app-admin/sudo nostackprotector.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ToolChain/CompilerFlags

says:

"Usually this is a result of calling ld instead of gcc during a build to perform linking"

This is what I encountered when modified the Makefile of libjpeg manually. Use gcc instead of ld solved the problem.

Comment: This seem to refer to `__stack_chk_fail_local` and not `__stack_chk_fail` which is explained as "Indicates a program was compiled to expect to have the stdlib available, but did not find it at runtime."