# undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail' error in linux

Tags: linux, unix

I get an error in linux while I try to link a certain number of objects by using a script file. The error is:

/usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a(stack_chk_fail_local.oS): In function `__stack_chk_fail_local ':
(.text+0x10): undefined reference to`__stack_chk_fail'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

What's the problem and how to overcome it?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492799/undefined-reference-to-stack-chk-fail

Comment: but i think there's a bit compatibility issue with  libdl.so .. 32/64 bit and the -m32 option. can we check the bit version of a .so file?

Comment: You could use `file lib.so` und see what it reports.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [undefined reference to \`\_\_stack\_chk\_fail'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492799/undefined-reference-to-stack-chk-fail)