# error while creating shared object (so ) in gcc

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, shared-libraries, ld

While trying to create a shared object in gcc i got this error

```
NMateLib.o: In function `set_interface_attribs':
NMateLib.c:(.text+0xbac): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail_local'
NMateLib.o: In function `set_blocking':
NMateLib.c:(.text+0xc45): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail_local'
ld: NMateLib.so: hidden symbol `__stack_chk_fail_local' isn't defined
ld: final link failed: Bad value
```

What wil be the problem?

Comment: *How* do you build? Please show the commands you use.

Comment: Maybe you can find something useful here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492799/undefined-reference-to-stack-chk-fail

Comment: I followed the commands given in this link http://blog.markloiseau.com/2013/01/linux-shared-object-tutorial/