# Cross-compile json-cpp for Synology RS812+

Tags: c++, json, cross-compiling, synology

Can anyone tell me how to cross compile json-cpp for Synology?

According to json-cpp `README` the `SContruct` shall be updated, which I have done.

I took a copy of the "linux-gcc" platform option, and configured the `g++` to `/usr/local/i686-linux-gnu/bin/i686-linux-gnu-g++` (downloaded toolchain for RS812). I compiled `json-cpp`, which seemed to go fine.

I then try to compile a little test cpp, using the following:

```
/usr/local/i686-linux-gnu/bin/i686-linux-gnu-g++ -Ijsoncpp/include -Ljsoncpp/libs/synology http_test.cpp -ljson
```

But then I get the following (linker) error:

```
jsoncpp/libs/synology/libjson.so: undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail@GLIBC_2.4'
```

Any inputs on what I'm missing when compiling `json-cpp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a generic problem of what to do when __stack_chk_fail is not defined.  For that we already have an answer!  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4492865/4323