# Openni2 error when running make

Tags: linux, makefile, kinect, openni

I downloaded Openni2 from github and run $make following the instruction in README. I got this error:

```
g++ -MD -MP -MT "./../../../Bin/Intermediate/x86-Release/libOpenNI2.jni.so/org_openni_NativeMethods.d ../../../Bin/Intermediate/x86-Release/libOpenNI2.jni.so/org_openni_NativeMethods.o" -c -msse3 -Wall -O2 -DNDEBUG -I. -I../../../Include -I../../../ThirdParty/PSCommon/XnLib/Include  -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -o ../../../Bin/Intermediate/x86-Release/libOpenNI2.jni.so/org_openni_NativeMethods.o org_openni_NativeMethods.cpp
g++ -o ../../../Bin/x86-Release/libOpenNI2.jni.so ./../../../Bin/Intermediate/x86-Release/libOpenNI2.jni.so/OpenNI.jni.o ./../../../Bin/Intermediate/x86-Release/libOpenNI2.jni.so/org_openni_NativeMethods.o  -L../../../Bin/x86-Release -lOpenNI2 -Wl,--no-undefined -shared
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a(stack_chk_fail_local.oS): In function `__stack_chk_fail_local':
(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [../../../Bin/x86-Release/libOpenNI2.jni.so] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/smalleyreaserch/OpenNI2/Wrappers/java/OpenNI.jni'
make: *** [Wrappers/java/OpenNI.jni] Error 2
```

I have all the required packages installed. Can anyone help me?
My system is Ubuntu 14.04 32 bits but the computer is 64 bits. would that be the reason why Im getting this error?

Comment: Is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492799/undefined-reference-to-stack-chk-fail of help here?

Comment: Can you explain to me how exactly do you link? Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question exactly. The linked answer lists two exact command line arguments that might be relevant.

Comment: So where should I add -fno-stack-protector to? Im new to openni.

Comment: Your `LDFLAGS` variable probably but I'm not sure. It depends on how the build is set up. You could consider asking the openni2 people for help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Some other people had this problem... but it was mainly in i686 computers... anyways, here is a possible solution.

First, make sure you have java and not openjava... I have read that this gives sometimes problems.

Secondly, use

```
export LDFLAGS+="-lc"
```

This should fix your problem, if not just leave a comment