# R package with Fortran module on Windows? undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'

Tags: r, fortran, gfortran, r-package

I created a R library that uses a Fortran module. Everything works like a charm on linux.

Now I'm trying to make it work on Windows. I cloned [my git repository](https://github.com/ignacio82/MyPi) on a windows computer, and when I press the `build and reload` button on Rstudio I get these errors:

```
==> Rcmd.exe INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source MyPi

* installing to library 'C:/Users/IMartinez/Documents/R/R-3.2.1/library'
* installing *source* package 'MyPi' ...
** libs
gfortran -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o MyPi.dll tmp.def Fpi.o -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/lib/x64 -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/lib -LC:/Users/IMARTI~1/DOCUME~1/R/R-32~1.1/bin/x64 -lR
Fpi.o: In function `__fortranpi_MOD_dboard':
Fpi.f90:(.text+0xd7): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
Fpi.o: In function `pi_':
Fpi.f90:(.text+0x249): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'MyPi'
* removing 'C:/Users/IMartinez/Documents/R/R-3.2.1/library/MyPi'

Exited with status 1.
```

What am I missing?

---

```
Module Fortranpi
IMPLICIT NONE
contains
subroutine dboard(darts, dartsscore)
  integer, intent(in)                    :: darts
  double precision, intent(out)          :: dartsscore
  double precision                       :: x_coord, y_coord
  integer                                :: score, n

score = 0
do n = 1, darts
  call random_number(x_coord)
  call random_number(y_coord)

  if ((x_coord**2 + y_coord**2) <= 1.0d0) then
  score = score + 1
  end if
end do

dartsscore = 4.0d0*score/darts

end subroutine dboard

subroutine pi(avepi, DARTS, ROUNDS) bind(C, name="pi_")
  use, intrinsic                         :: iso_c_binding, only : c_double, c_int
  real(c_double), intent(out)            ::  avepi
  integer(c_int), intent(in)             ::  DARTS, ROUNDS
  integer                                ::  MASTER, rank, i, n
  integer, allocatable                   ::  seed(:)
  double precision                       ::  pi_est, homepi, pirecv, pisum

! we set it to zero in the sequential run
rank = 0
! initialize the random number generator
! we make sure the seed is different for each task
call random_seed()
call random_seed(size = n)
allocate(seed(n))
seed = 12 + rank*11
call random_seed(put=seed(1:n))
deallocate(seed)

avepi = 0
do i = 0, ROUNDS-1
  call dboard(darts, pi_est)
  ! calculate the average value of pi over all iterations
  avepi = ((avepi*i) + pi_est)/(i + 1)
end do
end subroutine pi

end module Fortranpi
```

---

As recommended in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492799/undefined-reference-to-stack-chk-fail), I added `-fno-stack-protector -lssp` but it did not help. Maybe I added it in the wrong place?

[image: Rstudio]

---

I also tried doing by hand and I get these errors:

```
> system("R CMD SHLIB -fno-stack-protector -lssp ./src/Fpi.f90")
gfortran -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o src/Fpi.dll tmp.def ./src/Fpi.o -fno-stack-protector -lssp -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/lib/x64 -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/lib -LC:/Users/IMARTI~1/DOCUME~1/R/R-32~1.1/bin/x64 -lR
> dyn.load("./src/Fpi.dll")
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/IMartinez/Projects/MyPi/./src/Fpi.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application. 'C:/Users/IMartinez/Projects/MyPi/./src/Fpi.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

[image]

---

Following @cdeterman instructions i did the following:

1. I created `Makevars.win` in my `src` with the following line:

   PKG_FCFLAGS="-fno-stack-protector"
2. Then I also changed useDynLin(Fpi) in the NAMESPACE to useDynLib(MyPi).

This I what I get:

```
==> Rcmd.exe INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source MyPi

* installing to library 'C:/Users/IMartinez/Documents/R/R-3.2.1/library'
* installing *source* package 'MyPi' ...
** libs
gfortran -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o MyPi.dll tmp.def Fpi.o -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/lib/x64 -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/lib -LC:/Users/IMARTI~1/DOCUME~1/R/R-32~1.1/bin/x64 -lR
Fpi.o: In function `__fortranpi_MOD_dboard':
Fpi.f90:(.text+0xd7): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
Fpi.o: In function `pi_':
Fpi.f90:(.text+0x249): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
installing to C:/Users/IMartinez/Documents/R/R-3.2.1/library/MyPi/libs/x64
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  DLL 'MyPi' not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing 'C:/Users/IMartinez/Documents/R/R-3.2.1/library/MyPi'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/IMartinez/Documents/R/R-3.2.1/library/MyPi'

Exited with status 1.
```

Comment: Can this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492799/undefined-reference-to-stack-chk-fail

Comment: Thanks @VladimirF. I updated my question, but still no luck compiling on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `Makevars.win` file in your `src` directory with the following line.

```
PKG_FCFLAGS="-fno-stack-protector"
```

Then also change `useDynLib(Fpi)` in the NAMESPACE to `useDynLib(MyPi)` as that is what the package name is.

Try and build the package.  If the output doesn't show the flag being used, the environmental variable may not currently exist and fail work.  Not exactly sure why this would happen.  If this is the case, just simply initialize the environmental variable.

```
Sys.setenv(PKG_FCFLAGS = "")
```

This gets your package to build on my Windows system.

Comment: Thanks @cdeterman. I updated my question following your instructions. Sadly, is not working yet :(

Comment: Try creating the env variable with `Sys.setenv(PKG_FCFLAGS="")`.  It doesn't appear your build call was seeing it.

Comment: sorry for the stupid question, where do I put that code?

Comment: in the console, I assume you are using Rstudio so you can type it wherever you like and run it.  You could also set the flags directly in the `Sys.setenv` call.

Comment: Yes, i'm running rstudio. I run that command in the console and nothing happened. I tried to compile again and got the same error. Are you on windows 32 bits or something like that?

Comment: I deleted all the .so and dll files and tried again. Now is working!!!! Thanks a lot!!!!!!