# undefined reference to '__stack_chk_fail_local'

Tags: c++, linker

there is already a question asked: [undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492799/undefined-reference-to-stack-chk-fail) but that question is undefined reference to __stack_chk_fail and not __stack_chk_fail_local. this Is a linker error i am getting and i have searched but i don't know how to fix it. This is the exact error:

```
ld: binaries/GlobalDescriptorTable.o: in function 
`GlobalDescriptorTable::GlobalDescriptorTable()':
GlobalDescriptorTable.cpp:(.text+0xa6): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail_local'
```

and this is (a part of)the code in GlobalDescriptorTable.cpp:

```
GlobalDescriptorTable::GlobalDescriptorTable()
: nullSegmentSelector(0,0,0),
unusedSegmentSelector(0,0,0),
codeSegmentSelector(0,64*1024*1024,0x9A),
dataSegmentSelector(0,64*1024*1024,0x92)
{
    uint32 i[2];
    i[0] = (uint32)this;
    i[1] = sizeof(GlobalDescriptorTable) << 16;

    //lgdt is an assembly instruction that stands for load global descriptor table
    asm volatile("lgdt (%0)": :"p" (((uint8 *) i)+2));

}
```

Some other information:
i am using gcc compiler and ld linker with my own linker file,
I am using a class called GlobalDescriptorTable with a constructor and the error is coming from the constructor.

edit: also i am following a youtube tutorial

Comment: what do you get if you compile a main which call directly __stack_chk_fail_local() ?

Comment: I dont even know what is __stack_chk_fail_local , i kno it is a function, but i dont know what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

__stack_chk_fail_local is a function frim glibc which basically call stack_chk_fail.

```
/* On some architectures, this helps needless PIC pointer setup
   that would be needed just for the __stack_chk_fail call.  */

void __attribute__ ((noreturn)) attribute_hidden
__stack_chk_fail_local (void)
{
  __stack_chk_fail ();
}
```

In my Installation, this function is part of libc_nonshared.a which is a library which contains some functions not present in the shared library.

You can see these information by reading libc.so, mine can be found at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so`.

```
/* GNU ld script
   Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
   the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
GROUP ( /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a  AS_NEEDED ( /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ) )
```

The idea is to compile a simple test:

```
int main()
{
  __stack_chk_fail_local();
  return 0;
}
```

With the command line `gcc -o exec x.c -Wl,-Map,x.map` and see if it compile (you will get a warning). If it compiles , the problem is probably coming from your linker script and/or your command lines, otherwise your installation is corrupted or incomplete.

In the second case you need probably to reinstall libc6-dev if you are using Ubuntu for example.

Comment: actually i have already solved it before you answered by adding -fno-stack-protector. i am not going to delete this since others can view this question. i have solved it though but thank you for answering